# ng2-select server side

Tags: javascript, angular2

Есть библиотека [ng2-select](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select) для angular2.

Подскажите, есть ли возможность ее использовать как server-side.
По аналогии с select2 [пример](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге решено:

[issue на github'е](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/issues/97)

selectSingle.html:

```
<div style="width: 300px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <h3>Select a single city</h3>
  <ng-select [allowClear]="true"
              [items]="items | async"
              (data)="refreshValue($event)"
              (selected)="selected($event)"
              (removed)="removed($event)"
              (typed)="typed($event)"
              placeholder="No city selected">
  </ng-select>
  <pre>{{value.text}}</pre>
</div>
```

selectSingle.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, AsyncPipe} from '@angular/common';
import {SELECT_DIRECTIVES} from "../../ng2-select/components/select";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import {SelectSingleService} from "./selectSingle.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'select-single',
  pipes: [AsyncPipe],
  template: require('./selectSingle.html'),
  directives: [SELECT_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
  providers: [SelectSingleService]
})
export class SelectSingleComponent {

  constructor(private _DataService: SelectSingleService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this._DataService.getFiltered('');
  }

  public items:Observable<Array<any>>;

  private value:any = {};

  public selected(value:any):void {
    console.log('Selected value is: ', value);
  }

  public removed(value:any):void {
    console.log('Removed value is: ', value);
  }

  public typed(value:any):void {
    this.items = this._DataService.getFiltered(value);
  }

  public refreshValue(value:any):void {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

selectSingle.service.ts:

```
/**
 * Created by bmsdave on 07.06.16.
 */
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'

@Injectable()
export class SelectSingleService {

  private urlData = '/assets/json/country.json';

  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  getData():Observable<Array<any>> {
    return this.http.get(this.urlData)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getFiltered(filter: string):Observable<Array<any>> {
    return this.http.get(this.urlData)
    .map( (res) => {return this.extractFilteredData(res, filter)} )
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || [];
  }

  private extractFilteredData(res: Response, filter: string) {
    let body = res.json().filter((item: any) => { return item.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1});
    return body || [];
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

coutnry.json:

```
[
  {"text": "South Africa", "id": 1},
  {"text": "Palau", "id": 2},
  {"text": "Greenland", "id": 3},
  {"text": "Cote d'Ivoire", "id": 4}
]
```